# Flutter Project made by Android studio can be realsed for iOs

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio

I have questions about my project I have finally done from my flutter project on Android studio and tested it on many android devices working perfectly now I need to open the same project and test it on iOs my Questions is:-

1. Should I change something in code or file to open it on Xcode ?
2. Can I release it to ipa ?

Comment: You just need to open ios folder into xcode and then make a build from there for iOS

Answer (score 0):

#### Testing your Flutter iOS app on your iOS device

You should just follow the following steps:

1. Put the `Runner.xcworkspace` file inside the `ios` folder of your project folder
2. Open that project by double clicking and it'll launch in Xcode (if you have Xcode installed)
3. Then connect your iOS device (actual phone) to Xcode/MacBook using USB cable
4. Also, dont forget to configure `Team` and respectively `Bundle Identifier` (if you have any issues with `Bundle Identifier`):

In `Signing & Capabilities`, change the `Team` to `Personal` (for example);

In `General`, edit the `Bundle Identifier` to something that is **unique**.

And finally, you can run the app!